# matplotlib: AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from compare_plots import compare_plots

def make_plot(filename,totals):
    dict = {2 : 0, 3 : 0, 4 : 0, 5 : 0, 6 : 0, 7 : 0, 8 : 0, 9 : 0, 10 : 0, 11 : 0, 12 : 0}
    for i in totals :
        dict[i] += 1
    filename = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.hist(dict.values(), dict.keys())
    ax.set_xlabel('Total')
    ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(filename)

if __name__=='__main__':
    r1,r2=np.loadtxt('rolls.dat',unpack=True,delimiter=',')
    totals=r1+r2
    make_plot('my_plot.png',totals)
    if compare_plots('my_plot.png','instructors_plot.png'):
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('Keep trying.')
```

This code reads data from into two numpy arrays which are then totaled together and thrown into a function that is supposed to plot the totals as a [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD8Gk.png). It then calls a function to compare the plot with what it's supposed to look like.

When run, the program produces the error: `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'write'` I've managed to fix this error previously but I can't seem to recall how I did it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `write` attribute in your code. Is that **all** of your code ?

Comment: The only other code is the `compare_plots` function which has no `write` attribute either

Comment: and what is the line referred by the error ?

Comment: line 15: `plt.savefig(filename)` in `make_plot()`

Comment: use `collections.Counter`

Comment: have you tried `plt.savefig(ax)`

Answer (score 0):

Error is fixed by changing `filename` in line 15 `plt.savefig(filename)` into an f-string, `f'{filename}'` so that the line becomes `plt.savefig(f'{filename}')`

Comment: `str(filename)` instead of template string, why does this solve the problem, you pass `filename` as string argument, then assign it the result of a call to `figure()` (string is gone) and now you expect this object converted to string to get the value `my_plot.png`